# SQL Server how to show all the logins with database role memberships

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT * FROM syslogins
```

is not enough. It returns only logins with SQL Server authentication, but not those with Windows authentication.

I want to select all my logins, whether they use SQL Server or Windows authentication, along with the database role memberships the specific user.

I already tried :

```
SELECT  
    MEM.name AS MemberName ,
    ROL.name AS RoleName 
FROM  
    sys.database_role_members AS DRM 
INNER JOIN 
    sys.database_principals AS ROL ON DRM.role_principal_id = ROL.principal_id 
INNER JOIN 
    sys.database_principals AS MEM ON DRM.member_principal_id = MEM.principal_id 
INNER JOIN 
    sys.server_principals AS SP ON MEM.[sid] = SP.[sid]
```

but it return all the logins that I am looking for.

Comment: Do you want to see active (connected) or every authentication?

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
SELECT a.loginname,d.member_principal_id 
FROM syslogins a
       inner join  sysusers b
       on a.sid=b.sid
       inner join sys.database_principals c
       on b.sid=c.sid
       inner join sys.database_role_members d
       on d.role_principal_id=c.principal_id;
```